# template match XSLT1 skip subelements based on date

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I need to convert an xml document into another xml document based on date comparison using XSLT 1 (and EXSLT).

The XML in simplified form

```
<TAG>
    <A>
        <id>1234</id>
        <B>
            <id2>1</id2>
            <E>
                <C>2017-07-01</C>
                <D>2017-07-05</D>
            </E>
        </B>
        <B>
            <id2>2</id2>
            <E>
                <C>2017-07-21</C>
                <D>2017-07-28</D>
            </E>
        </B>
    </A>
</TAG>
```

I only want the B/E elements where C<=todaysdate<=D like (as of 2017-07-21)

```
<TAG>
    <A>
        <id>1234</id>
        <B>
            <id2>2</id2>
            <E>
                <C>2017-07-21</C>
                <D>2017-07-28</D>
            </E>
        </B>
    </A>
</TAG>
```

The xsl I have this far is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:variable name="today"
        select="translate(substring-before(date:date-time(), 'T'), '-', '')" />

    <xsl:template match="TAG/A">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="B/E">
        <xsl:variable name="start" select="translate(C, '-', '')" />
        <xsl:variable name="end" select="translate(D, '-', '')" />
        <xsl:if test="$start &gt; $today or $end &lt; $today">
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if
            test="($start &lt;= $today and not(D)) or ($start &lt;= $today and $end &gt;= $today)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which gives me

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TAG>
        <A>
                <id>1234</id>
                <B>
                        <id2>1</id2>

                </B>
                <B>
                        <id2>2</id2>
                        <E>
                                <C>2017-07-21</C>
                                <D>2017-07-28</D>
                        </E>
                </B>
        </A>
</TAG>
```

I need to get rid of the B tag - but cannot figure out how to do this. I've tried to use

```
    <xsl:template match="B">
        <xsl:variable name="start" select="translate(E/C, '-', '')" />
        <xsl:variable name="end" select="translate(E/D, '-', '')" />
        <xsl:if test="$start &gt; $today or $end &lt; $today">
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if
            test="($start &lt;= $today and not(D)) or ($start &lt;= $today and $end &gt;= $today)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

but then I get the full XML. When using integer values in C and D I know how to put the condition inside the match (to pick those where C=1 as shown below), but cannot figure that out for date comparison. Any help is appreciated. Sorry if this is a lame question - I am XSLT newbie :)

```
<xsl:template match="A[B/E/C='1']">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops. not(D) replaced with not(E/D) and works now

```
    <xsl:template match="B">
        <xsl:variable name="start" select="translate(E/C, '-', '')" />
        <xsl:variable name="end" select="translate(E/D, '-', '')" />
        <xsl:if test="$start &gt; $today or $end &lt; $today">
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if
            test="($start &lt;= $today and not(E/D)) or ($start &lt;= $today and $end &gt;= $today)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

However still interested in how I could put the date criteria inside the match of the template.

Comment: "*how I could put the date criteria inside the match of the template.*" You cannot have a reference to a variable in match pattern, so you would probably not want to do that. But you could do it by applying templates only to those `B` that pass the test.